# When I get data(array) from ajax response, how could I pass it to a partial which will generate a table?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a `Product` model in my rails app.
I want to implement a live search form in `products/index.html.erb` with `AJAX`.
I succeed in getting search results with AJAX with this:

```
<script>
    var $search_field = $("#key_word");
    var $table_body = $("#products_body");
    $search_field.keyup(function(){
      var search_keyword = $search_field.val();
      var search_options = {
      utf8: "✓",
      key_word: search_keyword
      }
    function display_results(data) {
      console.log(data);                     // Testing if I can get response correctly
    };
    $.getJSON("/products", search_options, display_results)
  }) ;
</script>
```

---

Inspecting dev tool's console, local server do send back the right search results when typing different words.[Here's a screenshot of dev tool console](https://ws3.sinaimg.cn/large/006tKfTcgy1fjiam2g8sij30zg09wado.jpg)

Previously I implemented a simple search form and create partial  **`views/products/_list_table`** to handle the table. In products_controller I defined `@products` so it can be used in partial.

Here is the `index` in products_controller:

```
 def index
   if params[:key_word].present?
     @products = Product.find_by_sql("# some sql code here")
   else
     @products = Product.all
   end
   set_price(@products)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @products}
   end
 end
```

And Here is the partial:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      .
      .
      .    
      <th>Manu</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="products_body">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= product.name%></td>
      <td><%= product.brand%></td>
      .
      .
      .

    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

But I don't know how to pass the ajax search result(in this case is the `data` followed `display_result()` function) to the partial.

I've tried using `$.each()` loop to generate a new form in scripts, but it makes code tedious. There should be some ways that can send the ajax data to partial and generate the table in a drier way.

Question: In this case, how to send data which I get from ajax request to partial `_list_table`, then use it to generate a products table ?

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax

> As an example, here's some CoffeeScript code that makes an Ajax request using the jQuery library:

```
 $.ajax(url: "/test").done (html) ->
      $("#results").append html
```

I don't know how to do this, but I need to understand this so I am reading more about the jquery `.ajax()` function at

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

My idea is, if your `.getJSON()` is successful, you should append to your html page the result.

```
$.getJSON("/products", search_options, display_results)
```

I think that you can get your data from the `AJAX response` and you need to change your `display_results()` function

Please comment my post once you find the solution so that I can read it. I ll be reading the documentation and If I understand the problem I will update my answer

### Post Request

based on the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nL7X1UMWsc), I think you should create a post request as follows

1. Your submit link will have an of `id='submitLink'`, while the fields from the form will have `id='name'` and `id='brand'`

   ```
   var $name = $('#name')
   var $brand = $('#brand')
   // When the link is clicked you trigger the function
   $('#submitLink').on('click', function() {
      // Which creates a variable 
      var product = {
         name: $name,
         brand: $brand
      };
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/products',
         data: product,
         success: function () {
             // js code to run on success
         },
         error: function () {
             // js code to run on failure
         }
      });
   });
   ```
2. You should be able to go to the network tab of your browser, find that post request and find in the body of your post request the form data you are submitting to the backend

[How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request#14551320)

Comment: Thanks for following my question @Fabrizio Bertoglio. I do want to append the results in html page, but the returned data is an array with many js objects in it, can't directly append to a table.  I need to convert it to something like `@products` then deal it with a loop.

Comment: @Caven ok that is easy, you just need to use a javascript loop for that array like in this guide and append every element to one of those fields https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: I've tried this. But how to embed ruby code `<%= link_to "+", add_to_cart_product_path(product), method: :post %>` into javascript.[Here's the js code.]  You can also check the partial in `views/products/_list_table.html.erb`

Comment: @Caven evaluate doing this as explained in the guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html because your approach using `AJAX` is very complex, anyway the post request need s to be done with `jQuery.post()` that will create a `POST` request to `/products` and will include in the body of your request the `params` from `product`. Maybe it s easy watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nL7X1UMWsc

Comment: I found a temporary solution: [datatables](https://datatables.net/). There is a brief introduction in [RailsCasts#340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables).